# It's possible to use SQLAlchemy to manage database roles privileges?

Tags: sqlalchemy

So, having the database tables been managed by SQLAlchemy, I wonder if is possible to use it to, also, to administrate roles privileges, like, for example, create user `read_user_a` and give it read permission to a table, or revoking permissions.

Comment: Should we assume that you mean something more sophisticated than just calling [.exec_driver_sql()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.exec_driver_sql)?

Comment: @GordThompson Well, yes, I have a table defined with SQLAlchemy, for example, and a user, I want to be able to say: this user should have select and insert privileges in this table. And then everything is magically done for me.
(. ❛ ᴗ ❛.)